# iOS mDNS service with non-standard type

Tags: ios, multicast, bonjour, zeroconf, mdns

In our iOS app we are creating mDNS/Bonjur service via CFNetServiceCreate. All is fine when service type is one of the standard types (like _http._tcp)

But we need to advertize our service with non-standard type (for custom devices). CFNetServiceCreate rejects registration with such types, leaving no options for us. After hour of searching we found nothing, seems like all mDNS examples under iOS uses the same CF stuff bounded with service type limitation

Is it possible to run custom mDNS service in iOS app? Can mDNSResponder ( http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-333.10/ ) help us here? Any help or links are welcome.